# Why can't Spring ToolSuite start on debug mode?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Yesterday, Spring ToolSuite started to act on me. I was running it on debug mode and all was fine. Suddenly I needed to restart tomcat for whatever reason and it wouldn't start on debug mode any longer. If I started tomcat normally, the application would be up in some 14,000 ms. Starting it on degub mode *used* to take similar times, but now it fails miserably, even if I set tomcat's timeout to a very long time (it failed even with 450 s).

I'd happily offer a log if I know where to find one. Console's output is all seemingly fine.

Ideas?

Comment: If you're running tomcat from the IDE you right click on the server and there should be a 'Browse deployment location...' if you go there and navigate a bit you should see the logs directory

Comment: Well, it shuts down the STS...